# How to Convert jpeg image into jpeg2000 lossless compression image?

Tags: java, jai, jpeg2000

I am compressing a image using java.

I want to compress the image in jpeg2000 lossless.

Please suggest solution.

```
File imageFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Chrysanthemum.jpg");
File compressedImageFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\decompjai.jpg");

InputStream is = new FileInputStream(imageFile);
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(compressedImageFile);

BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(is);

// get all image writers for JPG format
Iterator<ImageWriter> writers = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jp2k");

if (!writers.hasNext())
    throw new IllegalStateException("No writers found");

ImageWriter writer = (ImageWriter) writers.next();

J2KImageWriter
J2KImageWriteParam jwp =  (J2KImageWriteParam) writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
// J2KImageWriteParam jwp =  new J2KImageWriteParam();
boolean lossless = true;
jwp.setLossless(lossless);  

// jwp.setFilter(J2KImageWriteParam.FILTER_97);  
if (!lossless) {  
      jwp.setEncodingRate(8.0 / 2);  
}  

// ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
try {  
      ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(os);  
      writer.setOutput(ios);  
      writer.write(null, new IIOImage(image, null, null), jwp);  
      ios.flush();  
      ios.close();  
} catch (IOException e) {  
      e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

I am trying with the above code.

Comment: why JPG2000 and not other lossless formats like PNG? And in which format do you get the image? File, downlaod, Bitmap...?

Comment: Its a requriement for me.

Comment: Jpeg image or png image.

Comment: What have you got so far? It'll be easier to help you if you can provide some context in the form of code...

Comment: See the above my code, i am trying with that

Comment: You can use the Imagemagick.http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=17374. There are few commands, you can sneek-in easily using it.

Comment: In what way does the code you posted above not work for you?  Include relevant stack traces, error messages, samples of broken images, etc in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this](https://code.google.com/p/jj2000/) JPEG2000 Java Encoder/Decoder project. (you can find the source code [here](https://code.google.com/p/jj2000/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%253Fstate%253Dclosed))

Comment: Is another example you know means please post. The above link i cannot able to find some fruitful examples.

Comment: @Sivam You are expected to read the DOCUMENTATION yourself. SO is not a coding service.

Answer (score 0):

I'd first try [javax.ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html) as your system may have a provider for the JPEG2000 format.

Otherwise: http://www.deic.uab.cat/~francesc/ is apparently for java.